# Get starting and end index of a highlighted fragment in a searched field

Tags: .net, lucene, lucene.net, lucene-highlighter

"My search returns a highlighted fragment from a field. I want to know that in that field of particular searched document, where does that fragment starts and ends ?"

for instance.

consider i am searching "*highlighted fragment*" in above lines (consider the above para as single document).

I am setting my fragmenter as :

```
SimpleFragmenter fragmenter = 
            new SimpleFragmenter(30);
```

now the output of **GetBestFragment** is somewhat like : "*returns a highlighted fragment from*"

***Is it possible to get the starting and ending index of this fragment*** in the text above (say starting is 10 and ending is 45)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Highlighter does not returns that information when you use the methods getBestFragment. Behind the scene the Highlighter uses the [TokenGroup](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/TokenGroup.html) class
to get the start and the end index of each fragment. You could probably use that class.

Comment: actually, that hint was quite helpful. sorry for a really late response. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did just that a few months ago. You have to build custom [Formatter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/contrib-highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Formatter.html) and [Encoder](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/contrib-highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Encoder.html).
Basically, inside the highlighter, the formatter processes the tokens chosen for highlighting, while the encoder processes the rest of the tokens. In your case, you need the encoder to emit the empty each time it is called, and the formatter to emit the start index and the end index. They are indeed stored in the TokenGroup of the highlighted parts. Your highlighter should be constructed using these custom formatter and encoder.